# How to make a center aligned window title (window in wpf)

Tags: wpf

How do the center aligned ?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

The following works if you add it to your `Window Element` right after `Title="Name"`.

Add `TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"` to your window element.

Comment: When I have added center alignemnt and design view shows title at center of window. But project build, window title is again displayed on left side. Why this is not working?

Comment: Not only does this center the window title, it centers *every* `TextBlock` in the window

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use a custom Window chrome, as that is the default look of Microsoft Windows. [Here](http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/) is one example.