# Change window title alignment

Tags: wpf, alignment, title

How to change .NET WPF Application window title to be centre aligned throughout the application?

Comment: You'll probably have to create a custom style for your window in order to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919861/how-to-make-a-center-aligned-window-title-window-in-wpf